# Trying to connect to EJB on Wildfly 10.1 and getting: Session id hasn't been set for stateful component

Tags: java, ejb, jboss7.x, wildfly-10

I am using the following JNDI configuration:

```
    final String appName = "";
    final String moduleName = "session-beans";
    final String distinctName = "";
    final String beanName = "ItemStatefulRemote";
    final String viewClassName = ItemStatefulRemote.class.getName();
    final String toLookup = String.format("ejb:%s/%s/%s/%s!%s", appName, moduleName, distinctName, beanName, viewClassName);
    return (ItemStatefulRemote) context.lookup(toLookup);
```

While trying to connect with a `stateful` bean I am getting the following error:

```
Session id hasn't been set for stateful component:
```

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is a stateful bean so will have to add the session id which can be done by using the annotation `?stateful` along with the `viewClassName`.

So the code should be changed to:

```
 final String viewClassName = ItemStatefulRemote.class.getName()+"?stateful";
```